# Google Radar chart by Post Method

Tags: asp.net

I have asp.net page. In which i am loading multiple times google radar chart by post method in different frame.
So for multiple charts my page having multiple frames. at last i am getting radar chart but issue is that i am having data of last radar chart in all charts.

As shown below i am loading 2 radar chart in 2 div by frames from 2 different pages which posts data to google and creating chart but i am getting same result in both charts.

```
divRadarChart1.InnerHtml = "<iframe class='RadarSize' src='RadarChart.aspx' frameborder='0' width='680px' height='520px'></iframe>";

divRadarChart2.InnerHtml = "<iframe class='RadarSize' src='RadarChart1.aspx' frameborder='0' width='680px' height='520px'></iframe>";
```

Please reply me as soon.